# Some information about a .sh script that create an Ubuntu package?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, package

I have to work a pre-existent shell script that create an Ubuntu Package of a software developed by the company for which I work.

I am very new both in shell scripting and in the creation of Ubuntu package, so I have many doubts about it.

The script is a **.sh** file. Is this a **bash script**?

The second doubt is related to the first 2 lines of code that are:

```
JRE_I386="jre1.6.0_35-i386"
JRE_AMD64="jre1.6.0_35-x86_64"
```

I think that these line are declaring 2 variable named **JRE_I386** and **JRE_AMD64** that respectively declare the **JRE version** for the 32 bit package and for the 64 bit package that the script will create. Is it true?

But from where he takes the JRE? What exactly are the value jre1.6.0_35-i386 and jre1.6.0_35-x86_64"? Are they system variable that point to the JRE? or what?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: They are just strings. To know how they are used, you would need to post some code that uses the values of `JRE_I386` and/or `JRE_AMD64`.

Comment: If you are new to Linux and to shell scripting, **read quickly several books and tutorials**. [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) - and several wikipages on [Unix shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_Shell), [Syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall), [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) etc...

Comment: For what it's worth, the proper way to build a Debian package is simply [`dpkg-buildpackage`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's most probably a bash script and the values "jre1.6.0_35-i386" and "jre1.6.0_35-x86_64" are variables to be **used further down your script**, from the looks of them to fire the appropriate java version. The commands :

```
find / -name jre1.6.0_35-i386
find / -name jre1.6.0_35-x86_64
```

will then probably reveal the JRE install location/directories on your system. Look for how the variables are used in the script. Posting more of it will help eliminating my "probables".

Comment: This will probably only bring up the raw package files, not the actual binaries installed by those packages. Knowing what platform the OP is on would help direct his efforts. On Debian-derived Linux distributions, `/var/lib/dpkg/info/jre*.list` contains a list of files installed by this package.

Answer (score 2):

The extension of a UNIX file does not mean anything, it is just used for "human" reading and understanding. What tells you what program is used to execute the script is the first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or...

Regarding the variable declaration, yes, you are right, this is the way to declare variables. Then they will be used with `$JRE_I386`, etc (note that `$` is not used when declaring).

To know what is doing letter, you'd better post some more code.